# Change command window color scheme when running in terminal mode?

Tags: windows, matlab, terminal, customization, color-scheme

On a Windows system, running MATLAB using [`matlab -nojvm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/commonly-used-startup-options.html) produces a windows with a B/W color scheme:

[image]

However, I would very much prefer to change it to a darker scheme, such as the one I use in `cmd.exe`:

[image]

It would appear that none of the [standard color settings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/color-settings.html) have any effect on what this window looks like.

Is there some way to do this without patching the MATLAB executable?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-matlab-command-window-colors it is old but maybe it can lead you to what you are looking for. Might not work with the `-nojvm` option though..

Comment: @Arthur That page talks about programmatic access to color preferences of the IDE (i.e. the one that uses java) - so it's irrelevant to my question unfortunately.